# Accessing another host in an wifi network

Tags: wifi, firewalls, access-control

In a public wi-fi network if I know the IP of another host/laptop on that network I can add a default route in my host to that IP. Will this allow me to access services (or even the corporate network being if there is a VPN)?

I am pretty sure its not possible.. but wondering where exactly is this blocked ? When the wireless Access point block my host from connecting to any other IP on the same wi-fi network ?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this allow me to access services?

Depends on the wireless router. Some have [AP Isolation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147591/hiding-ips-in-a-public-wifi-network-by-isp/147595#147595), some don't.
Without specifics this is not really something we can answer better than "are cars red?".

As Bruce Schneier famously said before cutting down a Huffmann tree with his bare hands:

"Why don't you run NMap yourself and report back to me if you run into issues?"

> Where exactly is this blocked?

[At the router /access point. Specifically the MAC forwarding table.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/wireless-client-isolation-how-does-it-work-and-can-it-be-bypassed)

> I am pretty sure its not possible

Based on what result? We can pitch in much better if you share your research.

> When the wireless Access point block my host from connecting to any other IP on the same wi-fi network ?

Only when you speak unicode. It hates unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> I can add a default route in my host to that IP

If I'm getting what you're asking, you're going to add a route that configures your local machine to send all traffic this other host on the network. Correct?

> Will this allow me to access services (or even the corporate network
>   being if there is a VPN)?

No.

Just setting an arbitrary default route will do nothing. The host that you configure with your default route has to be able to understand what to do with the traffic you're sending it. If it's not a router, not configured to forward traffic, not configured to accept your traffic or manipulate it accordingly, then its' going to just ignore it and drop the traffic. You're computer will just not have internet access anymore.

This is also assuming the local WiFi even allows you to communicate with this other host.